# How do I avoid stackoverflow error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, stack-overflow

I want to make this Function:

calling **customPower 2 2** 
would give back 2^2 + 2^1 + 1

calling **customPower 3 3** 
would give back 3^3 + 3^2 + 3^1 + 1

Here is my code:

```
customPower :: Int -> Int -> Int
customPower x y
          | y == 0 = 1
          | y > 0 = (x^(y)) + (customPower x y-1)
```

It gives me stack overflow exception and I can't find where is the error. Everything seems fine.

Comment: You call `(customPower x y) -1` in the recursive case.

Comment: Another color for the bikeshed: `customPower x y = iterate ((1+).(x*)) 1 !! y`. If you want to get really cool, I bet this can be done as a variant of repeated squaring.

Comment: (Yep: you can compute `customPower x y` by summing up the bottom row of the matrix `[[1,0],[1,x]]^y`, and you can compute the latter with the usual repeated squaring algorithm.)

Comment: [Horner's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method): `foldr (\a r -> a + x*r) 0 [1 | i <- [0..y]]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operators have lower precedence than function calls, this means that your recursive call:

```
... + (customPower x y-1)
```

is interpreted as:

```
... + ((customPower x y)-1)
```

so you keep calling with the *same* parameters, therefore the recursion can never end.

We can fix this by adding brackets for `y-1`:

```
customPower :: Int -> Int -> Int
customPower x y
    | y > 0 = x^y + customPower x (y-1)
    | otherwise = 1
```

With this modifications, we do not get stuck in an infinite loop:

```
Prelude> customPower 5 3
156
```

We can rewrite the above by making use of [**`sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sum) and [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to implement this with a one-liner:

```
customPower :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
customPower x y = sum (map (x^) [0..y])
```

or we can use [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate):

```
customPower :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
customPower x y = sum (take (y+1) (iterate (x*) 1))
```

Due to Haskell's laziness, the above attempts will likely still result in a call stack that scales linear with the value of `y`: the functions are, like @dfeuer says, not tail recursive functions, we can however work with an accumulator here:

```
customPower :: Int -> Int -> Int
customPower x = go 1
    where go a y | y > 1 = a
                 | otherwise = seq a (go (a+x^y) (y-1))
```

since the above sum is equal to a simple formula, we can even calculate the value in *O(y log x)*:

```
   y
.————            y+1
 ╲     i       x    - 1
 ╱    x    =   ————————
*————            x - 1
  i=0
```

So we can calculate the value with:

```
customPower :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
customPower x y = div (x^(y+1) - 1) (x - 1)
```

This will usually work faster, although in a rare case where the result times `x -1` is larger than the maximum representable number of the type `a`, this will result in overflow and will return the wrong number.

Comment: It might make sense to mention that the OP's code (and your direct fix for it) is not tail recursive, so it will stack up delayed additions instead of performing them as it goes. `customPower = go 1 where go acc x y | y > 0 = go (x^y + acc) x (y - 1) | otherwise = acc` will fix the problem in optimized code. In unoptimized code, you'll need `go !acc x y = ...` or ``| y > 0 = acc `seq` ...``. The versions you give using `sum` will also build up thunks when not sufficiently optimized (and especially specialized).